# changing variable value from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created an application in angular js. In the application i'm having three controllers. The first controller MainController is in the body tag, within which i have another two  controller FileController and TypeController.

Inside the TypeController I've a select box having the model name data.selectedFileTypes which shows several filenames. Now within the FileController controller I've another select box with model name fileproperty.allowsFiles, and having `Yes` and `No` values. The first time it get initialized within the FileController controller.

But when i select a different file from the select of the model data.selectedFileTypes how can i change the select value again to `No` of the model fileproperty.allowsFiles from the ng-change function of the file select

an anyone please tell me some solution for this

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
        :
        :
        <div ng-controller="TypeController">
          <select ng-model="data.selectedFileTypes" ng-options="type.name for type in config.fileTypes ng-change="select()">
          </select>
        </div>
        :
        :
        <div ng-controller="FileController">
            <select ng-model="fileproperty.allowsFiles" ng-options="option.value as option.desc for option in files.options"></select>
        </div>
        :
        :
</body>
```

**script**

```
app.controller('TypeController', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    $scope.select = function()
    {
    :

    :
    }
}

app.controller('FileController', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    $scope.fileproperty.allowsFiles = 'No';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this method.

```
app.controller('MainController', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    $scope.select = function()
    {
    :
      $rootScope.selectedFiles = $scope.data.selectedFileTypes;
    :
    }
}
```

Inside your second controller

```
app.controller('FileController', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    $scope.$watch('selectedFiles', function () {
       $scope.fileproperty.allowsFiles = 'No';
   }, true);

}
```

You could also use `$broadcast` and `$on` here to handle this scenario:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    $scope.select = function()
    {
       $scope.$broadcast('someevent');
    }
}
```

Inside your second controller

```
app.controller('FileController', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    $scope.$on('someevent', function () {
       $scope.fileproperty.allowsFiles = 'No';
   });

}
```

Comment: Updated answer please check

Comment: See my example below. If you use a service in both controllers and bind to a property in the service, you don't need a watch. Dependency injection and two-way binding take care of updating the data.

Comment: @BKM what do you say about implementing service rather than watch

Comment: It depends upon you, which one you find more comfortable to use in your scenario

Comment: In your case you just want to trigger a change in the $scope value of your FileCointroller if some value changes in TypeController. So there isn't any need of using service here. If you are not interested in using $rootScope you could use $broadcast and $on events to handle the scenario.

Comment: Updated my answer with the usage of $broadcast and $on. Please check

Comment: IMHO using events is messy. The greatest thing about Angular is the two way binding. Why have two separate values that you need to track separately when you can bind your UI elements to the same variable in a service? Using an event to update the values means in future if you break the event your two variables can become out of sync.

Comment: the broadcasting is not working....take a look at this..http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JuEdr

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better practice to put shared properties into a service, then inject the service in both controllers.

Doesn't seem right to abuse a global namespace such as $rootScope when you don't have to.

Here's an example of a single service being bound to a select in one controller's scope and the same service being used in a second controller's scope to display the value in the service.

Here's a codepen: http://cdpn.io/LeirK and the snippets of code below

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <select ng-model='fileproperties.allowFiles'>
      <option id="No">No</option>
      <option id="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-controller="FileController">
      {{fileproperties.allowFiles}}
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'FilePropertiesService', function(scope, fileproperties) {
  scope.fileproperties = fileproperties;
}]);

app.controller('FileController', ['$scope', 'FilePropertiesService', function(scope, fileproperties) {
  scope.fileproperties = fileproperties
}]);

app.service('FilePropertiesService', function(){
  this.allowFiles = 'No';
});
```

Comment: but here `fileproperty.allowsFiles` model is within `FileController` right...so how can i change select using service

Comment: I'll update my example when I get back to my computer. But basically imagine `fileproperty` is `FruitService` and `allowFiles` is `selected`.

Comment: What I'm getting at is move the model to the service so you can share it. Use the controllers to manage the UI and the service to share your models. Tomorrow morning (AEST) I'll update my example to illustrate.

Comment: @user123 I've updated my snippets in this post as well as the codepen. You should fork the codepen and play with it and you will see how it works.

Comment: I think that in Angular you should first use two-way binding, then scope.$watch, and only then if it those two solutions don't solve your problem, then use events.